# How to download a private repository from Gitlab without exposing the access token in the url?

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, git-bash

I want to download a private repository from Gitlab using curl command (unfortunately I am obliged to do so). I know that the following works:

```
curl 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/2222/repository/archive?private_token=hlpat-21321' > your_project.tar.gz
```

where 21321 is the project id and hlpat-21321 is the access token (I put them  random).
I want to do the same thing but without exposing the access token directly. An idea would be to use stdin,meaning taking the token as an input from the user in the command line. How can I do it ?

Comment: Note that this does not download the *repository*. It obtains an archive of *one specific commit*. You can choose which commit with the `sha` parameter; the default is to get the tip commit of the default branch. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting curl man pages

> Starting in 7.55.0, this option can take an argument in @filename
> style, which then adds a header for each line in the input file. Using
> @- will make curl read the header file from stdin.

use it as header instead and pass the header from stdin

```
curl --header -@ ...url... <<< "PRIVATE-TOKEN: private_token"
```

This way you dont need to pass to url

Comment: That was not my question !

Comment: You are right i am sorry. I read it too fast

Comment: What curl version you have? curl --version

Comment: The version is curl 7.64.1

Comment: Try my updated answer